# What OAuth flow to use for Multiple APIs

Tags: oauth, oauth-2.0, identityserver3, identityserver4

I am currently working on a project that includes the following:

- One central identity server that authenticates users against Active Directory
- Several different APIs that different users have different levels of access to
- Several JS web apps that users log into in order to access the APIs

What authentication flow should be used in between the web apps and the identity server that allows the APIs to get information about the user and authorize the user within them? I'm a little stuck here.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You'd typically use the OAuth 2.0 Implicit Grant to obtain an access token for the JS web app that it can then use in calls to the APIs. The APIs can leverage the access token to find out about the Resource Owner who granted access to the API.

Update: see comment below about deprecation of Implicit over Code+PKCE.

Comment: The answer was correct at that time. Anyway I see the post is pretty outdated. For the new readers: the implicit flow from the JS is not recommended anymore for several security implications (client secret on the browser and access token exchanged through the frontchannel). Generally speaking it is recommended to adopt Auth code flow with PKCE.